# Hide Windows hidden files and folders that are on Windows network share

Tags: samba, cifs

I have fileserver based o Windows Server 2008 R2, that has some shares with hidden files on them. FS on which shares are created is NTFS
Now I've mounted those shares in ubuntu using CIFS, everything is working fine except that I can see all the hidden files, which is expected, but not desired. 
Is there any possible way not to display those files in ubuntu?

I found that thread:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1882753&s=c2495b99639759e45b80953f131d3d97, that says that this is possible if mounting ntfs partition. Any possible way to acomplishe this using cifs? maybe mounting netowk share using ntfs; would this work?

Comment: Did you check the config file for samba? See http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html from where they 1st talk about "hidden"?

Comment: I was looking at that, but can't find the right option. Any hint at what should I look?

Comment: One more thing. It would help a lot if i could just hide system folders like $RECYCLE.BIN and temp word files which starts with ~$

Comment: That will probably be `hide files = /$*/`

Comment: I know it's dumb question, but where do i put that?

Answer (score 10):

See [samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)

There are multiple flags/options which help to hide selected files through Samba share:

```
# hide files start with a dot (.)
hide dot files = yes

# hide selected files. example files start with ($)
hide files = /$*/

# hide pipes, sockets, devices ...
hide special files = yes

# hide files with no read permissions
hide unreadable = yes

# hide files with no write permissions
hide unwriteable files = yes
```

In most distributions, The configuration could be found at  /etc/samba/smb.conf

As a new user run this in terminal (advise: make a backup):

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Then restart samba service

```
sudo service samba restart
```

If you want Global share options insert those lines before the sections with ([]).
Otherwise with specific options for a shared path, put lines under the needed section or create new one. Example:

```
[foo]
path = /home/bar
read only = yes
hide dot files = yes
```

Comment: That is what is asked ;)

Comment: Note that at some systems, the restart command is `sudo service smbd restart`